# Date format for timestamp?

Tags: java

I have following Date String:

> 1477547160000+0800

Is there any date format for timestamp?

AFAIK, there is no date format to parse timestamp as in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: The number to the left are milliseconds of the epoch (like in `System.currentTimeMillis()`). The number to the right tells you the timezone.

Comment: How is the string formatted? Are these milliseconds since 1970? How is the time zone to be interpreted?

Comment: I get it from response, thus, I want to know if there is kind of "yyyy mm dd" to parse this String.. AFAIK, there isn't, but downvoted LOL

Comment: Is there some documentation that explains how the response is to be interpreted?

Comment: Unfortunately no... But need to be displayed as proper date string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number before `+` is epoch milliseconds, and the number after `+` is timezone offset, you can try this:

```
String input = "1477547160000+0800";
long epoch = Long.parseLong(input.substring(0, input.length() - 5));
int offset = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.length() - 5));
int offsetHour = offset / 100;
int offsetMin = offset % 100;

OffsetDateTime t = Instant
    .ofEpochMilli(epoch)
    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHoursMinutes(offsetHour, offsetMin));
```

Now you have `OffsetDateTime` instance, and you can convert it into `String` of any format you want. The default is:

```
t.toString() => "2016-10-27T13:46+08:00"
```

If you want specific format, you can use `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
t.format(new DateTimeFormatter(your_format_here));
```